# How to do a many to many subquery in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with MySql 5.1 and am building my first many-to-many database. I understand the concepts, I have 3 tables:

- `Albums`, with a unique ID
- `Genres`, with a unique ID
- `album_genres` with columns for each of the ID's from Albums and Genres.

The issue I am having is that, of course, 1 album can have multiple genres. But when I do a search, I'm really in the dark about how to structure it so during searches, I get all the genres for each individual album. Please note, this is not the loading of 1 album, but doing a search that will net 1 or more albums.

Sorry I don't really have anything to show what I've tried because I'm not even sure where to begin.

I'm sure it's easy enough. But all the tutorials I could find only address the basics of M2M but not how to get multiple matching entries.

After looking at many great suggestions, I have built this query:

```
SELECT 
album.album_title,
Concat(genre.genre_id, ',') as GenreName, 
count(album.album_id) as GenreCount
FROM $this->album_tbl album
JOIN wp_musicmgr_albgnr albgnr ON albgnr.albgnr_album_fk = album.album_id
JOIN $this->genre_tbl genre ON genre.genre_id = albgnr.albgnr_genre_fk
GROUP BY album.album_id
```

Which is producing this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [album_title] => album q
        [GenreName] => 1,
        [GenreCount] => 3
    )

However, as you can see. Despite having a count of 3 hits on genres, it is listing the first one.
```

Comment: Do, you want many 2 many between which tables? You have specified only 2 tables - "Album" and "Genre". Which is the 3rd one ? Also how is referential integrity related.. Please clarify.

Comment: Please check again, there are 3 tables; albums, genres and a table with ID's for both albums and genres to create the M2M connections.

Comment: So, you want to search by multiple album names, and that would fetch you all the corresponding genres ??

Comment: @abhihitcaps - I appreciate your attempt to help. But both comments you have made were addressed in my post. 'Please note, this is not the loading of 1 album, but doing a search that will net 1 or more albums.'

Comment: Yes Lee, I have posted an answer(SQL) as per my understanding. I have used a like for wild char search. You can also use IN concept. Do review my answer.I hope it solves your confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the question you need output like

```
AlbumName  | Genre1,Genre2.........
```

FOr this you need to use **GroupBy**

```
SELECT A.album_name as AlbumName, GROUP_CONCAT(G.genre_name) as GenreName, count(A.ID) as GenreCount  
FROM Album A 
JOIN album_genres AG 
   ON (A.ID = AG.album_ID)
JOIN Genre G
   ON (G.ID = AG.genre_ID)
Group by A.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Elvin. It is very close. However, I am not able to get all the genre ID's (I am getting ID's instead of names). Please take a look at my edit with my query and results.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss: Most likely Elvin meant `GROUP_CONCAT` instead of `CONCAT`.

Comment: Thanks. That is it AND instead of ',', just ''. Otherwise it is doubling-up on the commas.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss: I have updated the answer as ',' used in concat()

Comment: Note: `GROUP_CONCAT` has a maximum length limit. Default limit is 1024, but can changed by modifying `group_concat_max_len`. Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

Join on the two tables.

```
SELECT cols FROM Albums
JOIN album_genres USING (albumID)
JOIN Genres USING (genreID)
WHERE albumName LIKE :search
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all Genres of an Album the query would be

```
SELECT A.album_name, G.genre_name FROM Album A 
JOIN album_genres R 
    ON (A.ID = R.album_ID)
JOIN Genre G
    ON (G.ID = R.genre_ID)

WHERE A.ID = '5'
```

Where 5 would be the album unique id. The basic concept is that you should join the 3 tables, and use JOIN - ON to match the ids of each columns in the relationship table to the entity table one

**EDIT:** If you want a list of every album with every genre like this one:

Album - Genre

Al01  - Rock

Al02  - Rock

Al01  - Rock

Al01  - Metal

Al03  - Metal

just remove the `WHERE A.ID = '5'`.

Comment: This is not quite giving the results I was expecting. Instead of getting multiple genres for each album, I am getting the album entry once for each genre. How do I get just 1 entry with a list of genres?

Answer (score 0):

Select * from 
Albums a, Genres g, album_genres ag
where a.unique_id = ag.a_unique_id and g.unique_id = ag.g_unique_id and 
a.name like '%***album-name***%'

***album-name*** is the value of album in table *album*

Also in place of star(*) in ***Select ****, please do put columns name's from Gener table.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated (New Answer):**

Note: Tested.

```
select a.name, group_concat(g.name separator ', ') 
from albums a 
inner join album_genre ag on a.id = ag.albumid 
inner join genres g on ag.genreid = g.id 
group by a.id;
```

Note: `GROUP_CONCAT` has a maximum length limit. Default limit is 1024, but can changed by modifying `group_concat_max_len`. Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat


**Old answer:**

Search for Albums:

```
SELECT a.album_name, a.AlbumId FROM `Albums` a 
INNER JOIN `album_genres` ag on a.AlbumId = ag.AlbumId
INNER JOIN `Genres` g on ag.GenreId = g.GenreId
WHERE 
a.album_name = 'Michael Learns To Dance' AND
g.genre_name = 'ROCK'
GROUP BY a.AlbumId;
```

Foreach row... perform another search query:

```
SELECT g.genre_name FROM `Genres` g
INNER JOIN `album_genres` ag on g.GenreId = ag.GenreId
WHERE ag.AlbumId = 1;
```

*....[continue for next row]....*

```
....
WHERE ag.AlbumId = 2;
WHERE ag.AlbumId = 3;
WHERE ag.AlbumId = 4;
......
WHERE ag.AlbumId = 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I should have mentioned in my post that this idea did cross my mind. But it seems like it would be quite slow and bulky.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss I have updated my answer. Another solution is added.